# PHP receives and sends data

Tags: php

I have the following php code, it sends the data to a leads tool.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://mkt.university-private.internal/form/submit",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('mauticform[f_email]' => 'gbsilva@gmail.com','mauticform[f_name]' => 'Gabriel','mauticform[formId]' => '5'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "X-Forwarded-For: 91.92.103.192"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

The problem is that I have to enter the data manually in the php script.

I now have an CRM that does a POST and sends the following data in body form-data:

`email=gbsilva@40gmail.com&name=Gabriel&IP=91.92.103.192&formId=5`

what i need is that my php code accepts to receive an CRM post with these values ​​above and make the request in my leads tool with the data that came from CRM.

on my erp, i can call a url and i will call the url of my script.php

he needs before sending convert and put the name of the fields between this nomenclature, 
the leads tool only accepts fields with this nomenclature:

`mauticform[f_FIELDNAME]`

Can anyone help

Comment: why dont use  http_builder_query($array)  for post  fields

Comment: I don't have so much knowledge in PHP, can I help my friend?

Comment: where ? how  ı can help

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/dilosurucu/  add me from facebook ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy just need to utilize `$_POST` to transfer values to variables and then use it

```
<?php

$P_email = $_POST['email'];
$P_name = $_POST['name'];
$P_formId = $_POST['formId'];
$P_ip = $_POST['IP'];

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://mkt.university-private.internal/form/submit",   
  //..hidden                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('mauticform[f_email]' => $P_email,'mauticform[f_name]' => $P_name,'mauticform[formId]' => $P_formId),

  //hidden

  //*update* FOR IP
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "X-Forwarded-For: $P_ip"
  ),
));


//..
```

**UPDATE**: So to address the dynamic variable names

```
//Create an array to hold the name=value pairs
$P_arr = [];
//Loop over $_POST and populate $P_arr
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $P_arr[$key] = $value; 
   // $key will run through all those keys' values you sent //name ,email ..
   // so will $value but on the literals like "gbsilva@40gmail.com", "Gabriel"
}

/* We have now an array of key value pairs */
// adjust the KEYs to "mauticform"'s format before using
$mauticformArr = [];

foreach($P_arr as $key=>$value){
   if($key != 'IP'){
      if($key!= 'formId')
        $mauticformArr['mauticform[f_'.$key .']'] = $value;
      else
        $mauticformArr['mauticform['.$key .']'] = $value;       
   }
}

// Then use inside you code as
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://mkt.university-private.internal/form/submit",   
  //..hidden                
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $mauticformArr,
  //..hidden 
  //..
```

Comment: Brilliant friend, that was it.

One doubt about the

  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
    "X-Forwarded-For: 91.92.103.192"
  ),

It arrives dynamic, and I also need to do the same thing.

Can you help me?

Comment: I have to pass the IP address through X-Forwarded-For in header

Comment: incredible, incredible incredible ...

I do not know how to thank you.


You can help me with just one more thing, imagine that the fields can be dynamic ...

Name, email, postal code, country ..

There is a way to get all the fields that come.

Minus the

$ P_ip "

And automatically add CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

so that I don’t need to keep adding variables directly to my php for each new field.

Comment: Yes that's possible too

Comment: strange ... this one sends the data all empty here on the other side ...

Looks like it's coming without the f_

Comment: discovered the problem ... it really comes without the f_

But if I add it to the

 $mauticformArr['mauticform[f_'.$key .']'] = $value;

I have a problem because it changes the formId ...

FormId cannot contain f_

Comment: I've updated the second foreach loop that should do

Comment: brilliant ... i don't know how to thank you ... thanks for that spirit of being able to help people, you were amazing man!

Thank you!

Comment: That was nothing really :)

Answer (score 0):

You may find that "Guzzle" works better than actually using CURL ...